# SQL(inner join with select statement)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have 2 tables auction and customer

auction

```
custId|itemName|yearsUsed|bidPrice
   1  | MacBook|    2    |  1500
   3  |  Dell  |    1    |  1000
   2  | MacBook|    2    |  1500
```

customer

```
 custId|custName
   1   | tom
   2   | jerry
   3   | susan
```

I want to query for those customers name, the item name and the bidding price for who have bided the same price for an item and the years used by the owner as well

The following query returns the item name which has the same bidding price by the customers

```
  SELECT ac.itemName,
         ac.yearsUsed,
         ac.bidPrice 
    FROM auction ac 
GROUP BY ac.itemName,
         ac.yearsUsed,
         ac.bidPrice 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

output

```
itemName yearsUsed  bidPrice
----------------------------
 MacBook     2       1500
```

Now I want to query for the customer name who had bid the same price for the item

```
  SELECT ac.itemName,
         ac.yearsUsed,
         ac.bidPrice 
    FROM auction ac 
         INNER JOIN (
                     SELECT custName 
                       FROM customer
                    ) c 
               ON c.custId = ac.custId 
GROUP BY ac.itemName,
         ac.yearsUsed,
         ac.bidPrice 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I get an error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA_00904:"C"."CUSTID": invalid identifier
```

I am using sqlplus

Answer (score 4):

You must add `custid` in the inner query.

```
SELECT 
  ac.itemName,
  ac.yearsUsed,
  ac.bidPrice 
FROM 
 auction ac INNER JOIN
    (SELECT custName,
      -- The following CUSTID was missing:
     CUSTID 
     FROM customer) c ON c.custId = ac.custId 
GROUP BY ac.itemName,ac.yearsUsed,ac.bidPrice 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

*However*, in your case, the *subquery* is not necessary.

```
SELECT 
  ac.itemName,
  ac.yearsUsed,
  ac.bidPrice 
FROM 
 auction ac INNER JOIN
 customer c ON c.custId = ac.custId 
GROUP BY 
   ac.itemName,
   ac.yearsUsed,
   ac.bidPrice 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you also need, as per your comment, the customers' names, then you need to go with the analytical expression `count(*) over(...)`:

```
select
  custName,
   itemName,
   yearsUsed,
   bidPrice
from (
  SELECT 
    c.custName,
    ac.itemName,
    ac.yearsUsed,
    ac.bidPrice,
    count(*) over (partition by 
                   ac.itemName, 
                   ac.yearsUsed, 
                   ac.bidPrice) cnt
  FROM 
   auction ac INNER JOIN
   customer c ON c.custId = ac.custId 
)
where
  cnt > 1
```

[see also this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aaaf1/12)

Comment: the first sql query does not return the customer name and that's what I am struggling with because I need to output the customer name who bid the same price  for an item as well

Comment: Which customer name do you want, *tom* or *jerry*, and why?

Comment: I need to output both of their names because they had bid for the same price for the item "Macbook" as well as the itemName,yearUsed and bidPrice for that item "Macbook"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
     SELECT 
ac.itemName,
ac.yearsUsed,
ac.bidPrice,
c.custName
 FROM auction ac 
LEFT JOIN customer c ON c.custId = ac.custId 
GROUP BY ac.itemName,ac.yearsUsed,ac.bidPrice 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`cust_id` is missing from the inner `select`. By why use an inner `select`?

```
select ac.itemname
,      ac.yearsused
,      ac.bidprice
from   auction ac
inner
join   customer c
on     c.custid = ac.custid
group
by     ac.itemname
,      ac.yearsused
,      ac.bidprice
having count(*) > 1
;
```

Comment: I'm not really good in sql. so I am trying out options that comes to my mind to achieve my output

Comment: @user3213758: Then just use the `join`. The inner `select` does not add anything.

Comment: sorry what if I need to also output those customer name who bid the same price for an item as well?

Comment: That will make things more complex. You will have to find the highest price, and then select the customers having bid that price. I would say to create a new question for that, post the link and I will take a look.